# ifconfig + device interrupt

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, ifconfig

what is the -  device interrupt 90  memory 0x434000000-934fff

from ifconfig command

is it indicate on network problem ? , what we need to check on the OS linux ?

```
    ifconfig -a
    RX errors 1971059972  dropped 503931  overruns 65  frame 1971059907
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 90  memory 0x96000000-967fffff
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 102  memory 0x95000000-957fffff
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
```

Comment: Does 'ip a' work fine? And for which type of devices is it reported?

Comment: what I need to capture from the command - ip a ?

Comment: check any messages from dmesg relating to network connections

Comment: yes but what to capture from the dmesg its along output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very poor way to look for error information.  **Not every word with the string "err" in it means "error"**.  The word "interrupt" just happens to contain "err".  **Not all output of the `ifconfig` command is error messages.**  It does, after all, report interface configuration.

Comment: if the answer is accepted, the question should be positive pointed.  only good questions are answered agreed? else edit the question.   i mean, if someone wants to know the answer, thats why they are here.  Why should a users points be takes from the answer??  Something fundamentally wrong with that system..  So I upvoted question, and now i get negative points, what kind of socialist place is this?